# What's the difference between ～きれる and ～あげる?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between these two?

N3 grammar masu form ＋　切れる
N3 grammar masu form ＋　上げる

Answer (score 1):

`masu+きれる` means to be able to perform an action to its completion.
`masu+あげる` means to fully complete a specific task (usually involving production).

For masu+きれる (or masu+きれない), the meaning is related to any action which has the potential for degrees of completion. The きれる part refers specifically to whether someone is able to complete it. For example, let's say you ordered a large meal. You might be able to eat all of it or not. Depending on the outcome, you would use 食べきれる or 食べきれない to express whether or not you were able to eat all of the meal, i.e. to finish the eating to its completion. Another example:

> 数えきれないほどの時間 countless hours (lit. so much time it cannot be fully counted).

For masu+あげる, there is typically a task which is being done. This is often used to describe the production of a finished item or thing, such as making or building something. It involves the process of finishing off a task and emerging with a tangible final result. For example,

> 論文を書き上げる to finish writing a thesis
>   マフラーを編み上げる to finish knitting the scarf

Simply put, `masu+きれる` describes potential (can you complete the action), whereas `masu+あげる` describes the completion of a task-based process.